# Asp web api vs wcf for point of sales application

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api, wcf-data-services

I'm planning to develop a pos application for restaurant. Client will be using pc and mobile. Application will be used in local area connection. I'm still considering whether to go with wcf or web api. What are the advantages of using wcf/web api for the type of application i'm building?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for specific technical issues, so your question is off topic.  Be careful, the the auto-ban algorithm is very harsh on new users.  It does not take many bad questions for new users to get banned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use WCF to create reliable, secure web services that accessible over a variety of transports.
- Use ASP.NET Web API to create HTTP-based services that are accessible from a wide variety of clients.
- Use ASP.NET Web API if you are creating and designing new REST-style services. Although WCF provides some support for writing REST-style services, the support for REST in ASP.NET Web API is more complete and all future REST feature improvements will be made in ASP.NET Web API.
- If you have an existing WCF service and you want to expose additional REST endpoints, use WCF and the WebHttpBinding.

from the official [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172.aspx).

Essentially, my take on this is that WCF is much more difficult to work with, and not completely compatible out of the box with many mobile clients, so only use it if you know that it's something you need.